# Write To a specific line of a file in a loop using batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, text-files, text-manipulation

I want to write some text in specific lines of a file, for example I want to write in lines 12 and 13, and also I need to do this every 5 seconds.

How to do it using batch script?

Comment: StackOverflow is geared toward people that can supply some of their own script, to enhance and fix. Try http://www.dostips.com/forum/ or http://superuser.com/ if you want a script written for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my routine, I will advise you that the code is not perfect for peculiars textfiles for example if a line of text starts with a `]` character, but for simple/normal textfiles this would work perfectly, just try it:

```
@Echo OFF


:: TEXT MANIPULATOR ROUTINE v0.5
:: by Elektro H@cker


REM SYNTAX:
::
:: TEXTMAN [ACTION] [LINE(S)] [FILE] [TEXT]
::
:: * [LINE(S)] parameter is Optional for some actions
:: * [TEXT] parameter is Optional for some actions


REM ACTIONS:
::
::  AB  = ADD_BEGINNING      * Add text to the beginning of a line.
::  AE  = ADD_ENDING         * Add text to the end of a line.
::  E   = ERASE              * Delete a line.
::  I   = INSERT             * Add a empty line (Or a line with text).
::  RL  = REPLACE_LINE       * Replace a entire line.
::  RS  = REPLACE_STRING     * Replace word from line.
::  RSA = REPLACE_STRING_ALL * Replace word from all lines.
::  C+  = CHARACTER_PLUS     * Delete the first "X" characters from all lines.
::  C-  = CHARACTER_LESS     * Delete the last  "X" characters from all lines.
::  L+  = LINE_PLUS          * Cut the first "X" amount of lines.
::  L-  = LINE_LESS          * Cut the last  "X" amount of lines.
::  GL  = GET_LINE           * Delete all except "X" line.
::  GR  = GET_RANGE          * Delete all except "X" range of lines.


REM EXAMPLES:
::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the line 3                                                       ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN E 3 "Test.txt"                                            ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                        
:: Add a string to the beginning of line 3                                 ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN AL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                      
:: Add a string to the end of line 3.                                      ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN AR 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                       
:: Add a empty line at line 3.                                             ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt"                                            ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                       
:: Add a line with a word at line 3.                                       ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                           ::
::                                                                         ::    
:: Replace the line 3 with "Elektro H@cker".                               ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Replace the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in line 3.                      ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RS 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"                        ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Replace the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in all lines.                   ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RSA "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"                         ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the first 3 characters in all lines.                             ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN C+ 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the last 3 characters in all lines.                              ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN C- 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the first 3 lines.                                               ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN L+ 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the last 3 lines.                                                ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN L- 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete all except the line number 3.                                    ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN SL 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete all except the 3 to 9 range of lines.                            ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN SR 3 9 "Test.txt"                                         ::
::                                                                         ::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::


:TEXTMAN
(SET /A "A=0", "LINE=0", "TOTAL_LINES=0")  &  (CALL :%~1 %* || (ECHO Invalid parameter & Exit /B 1)) & (GOTO:EOF)
:AB
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE (if "%%B" EQU "" ((Echo %~4)>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %~4%%B)>> "%~3.NEW"))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:AE
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE ((Echo %%B%~4)>> "%~3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:E
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B) >> "%~3.NEW"))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:I
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF     "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (IF NOT "%~4" EQU "" ((Echo %~4) >> "%~3.NEW") ELSE (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW"))" & (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW"))))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RL
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE ((Echo %~4)>> "%~3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RS
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE (CALL SET "STRING=%%B" &&     (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~4=%~5%%)>> "%~3.NEW")))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RSA
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~2" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (CALL SET "STRING=%%B" && (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~2.NEW") ELSE ((CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~3=%~4%%)>>"%~2.NEW")))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~2") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C+
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~%~2%% >>      "%~3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C-
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~0,-%~2%% >>   "%~3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L+
(Call SET /A "A=%~2") && (Call TYPE "%~3" |@MORE +%%A%% > "%~3.NEW") && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L-
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES+=1")) & (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES-=%~2-1") & (For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" & Call echo "%%LINE%%"|@FIND "%%TOTAL_LINES%%" >NUL) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3" && GOTO:EOF) || (Echo %%B >> "%~3.NEW"))
:GL
(Call SET /A "A=%~2" && Call SET /A "A-=1") && (Call TYPE "%~3" |@MORE +%%A%% > "%temp%\getline.tmp") && (For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%temp%\getline.tmp" ^| find /n /v ""') DO ((if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)> "%~3.NEW"))) && ((CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF))) 
:GR
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~4" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "(IF "%%LINE%%" GEQ "%~2" IF "%%LINE%%" LEQ "%~3" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~4.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~4.NEW"))) && (IF "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~3" Exit /B 1)" || ((CALL :RENAMER "%~4") & (GOTO:EOF)))))

:RENAMER
(REN "%~1" "%~nx1.BAK") & (MOVE /Y "%~1.BAK" "%TEMP%\" >NUL) & (REN "%~1.NEW" "%~nx1") & (GOTO:EOF)
```

Example usage to insert a new line with custom text in line 12:

```
Call :TEXTMAN I 12 "File.txt" "Text"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Win32 you could try scripting edlin.

Edlin.script

```
12
Write new text on line 12
13
Write newtext on line 13
e
```

Command line

```
edlin "c:\something\somefile.txt < c:\edlin.script
```